# How to send data using TCP socket in windows for Spark Structured Streaming

Tags: apache-spark, websocket, spark-structured-streaming

I want to create and send data using a TCP socket so that I can use that as a Streaming source for Spark Structured Streaming. I am using Windows OS. I tried using Putty to SSH to my localhost but that is asking for login and password which I don't know what to give.

Can anyone please help me to achieve this.
Thanks in Advance !!

Answer (score 1):

Here I got my answer. Just follow these steps:

1. Install netcat from [here][1]
2. After Downloading netcat go to the netcat directory installed and open it in cmd.
3. now run: `nc -l -p [YourPortNumber]`
4. Now run the following Spark Structured streaming code

   ```scala
      val df = spark
            .readStream
            .format("socket")
            .option("host", "your host")
            .option("port", "your port")
            .load()

      df.selectExpr("CAST(value AS STRING)")
        .writeStream
        .format("console")
        .option("truncate", "false")
        .start()
        .awaitTermination()
   ```
5. Now start typing your data in the cmd window where your socket was listening to.

If you want to check whether your port is listening to the mentioned port no. go to the cmd window and type:

```
telnet yourhost yourport
```

and enter. Now start typing and see whether data is getting received to your previous cmd-window where you were listening to the port. Data must be input into the window where you were running the "netcat" application, from.

Be aware that not all ports allow this listening; in my system "9999" did and "4444" did not.
[1]: https://linhost.info/2011/05/netcat-for-windows/